# Is it easy to apply SSL to an already built website?

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I'm building a website in ASP.NET, and I want it to have users so I'm creating a login page, database, aspx pages, etc, etc.

But I also want to implement SSL for extra security later on, but I don't know have the slightest idea if that will be a difficult or annoying, I have never implemented SSL for a website. So I'm wondering, is it "easy" or "hard" to apply SSL to my website after it's already built?

Do I have to build my website with SSL in mind from the start, or can I learn about it afterwards and then apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily add it to an existing site. Just obtain the certificate, set it up in IIS and you are good to go:

[How do I add HTTPS to my asp.net website for account login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921908/how-do-i-add-https-to-my-asp-net-website-for-account-login)

[Setting up SSL with ASP.NET - Part 1 of 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_gVxaXHM7U)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure SSL after deploying you website. No need to take extra measure at the time of building your web site and of-course it is very easy to implement. SSL configuration is used to encrypt the connections with your web-site. You can buy or use self signed certificate to encrypt the connection. Try these link for more info:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7